# How Can I return the count of a specific value in a table column where this column is dynamic?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table shown if Table.JPG. I would like to count the number of times paid comes up in Jun-17. Please note that the month-year is dynamic in the count.

[image: Table.JPG]

For example, the current month-year is Jun-17 so count how many times "paid" comes up in **Jun-17**. If the month-year is Sep-17, find the number of times "paid" comes up in column **SEP-17**.

In a nutshell, match the current month-year (mmm-yy) to the column on the table with the same header as the current month-year and then count the number of times "paid" comes up in that column.

Comment: Are they dates or text?

Comment: `Countif()`, no? What have you tried

Comment: The table headers are dates

Comment: What date, the first day of the month?

Comment: @BruceWayne, I tried a Countif() but I kept on getting stuck in the generating the range. I, however, came across an answered question that may be helpful so I'm about to try it. The link is https://superuser.com/questions/461075/dynamically-reference-a-named-table-column-via-cell-content-in-excel

Comment: @ScottCraner yes because no dates were specified so Excel automatically makes it the first day of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX() to set the range:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(A:D,0,MATCH("6/1/2017",1:1,0)),"Paid")
```

If you are using a table named Table 1

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH("Jun-17",Table1[#Headers],0)),"Paid")
```

Comment: Shouldn't A:D be Table1 given I am working with a table and then the match is dynamic so shouldn't it be something like. `=COUNTIF(INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH((TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())), "mmm-yy")),1:1,0)),"Paid")`

Comment: See edit. @MrMarho

Answer (score 1):

Scott Craner has answered the question above perfectly but I would like to add a quick edit to make the date changing dynamic in case anyone ever encounters this problem.

`=COUNTIF(INDEX(Table1,0,MATCH(TEXT(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()), DAY(TODAY())), "mmm-yy"),Table1[#Headers],0)),"Paid")`

This can still be edited based on requirements of the dynamic change.