# Excel 2016 - Use text in cell as table column reference

Tags: microsoft-excel

this is my first time posting here so I'm sorry in advance if I'm missing any crucial info. Please let me know!

I have a table with data similar to this: https://ibb.co/Jx631Bq

I want the two columns on the right (L and M) to contain the numbers from the column in the table which has the the same column name as the cells on the right (in this case columns G and J).

The formula I'd like would be something like this: =Table[@$L$1] but obviously it doesn't work.

I don't want to do it with direct cell references because my real workbook is much more complicated than this example and I'd like to make a formula I can put in other cells and it always looks for the data in the table which matches the column title.

Please let me know if I need to add anything! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tables, you can use structured references to access the data region for a column by the name of its column. You can then use the `INDEX` function to select a row within that column.

Here is an example:

[image: Formulas]

To access the data region for a column in the table, we use the structured reference format of `TableName[[#Data],[ColumnName]]`, where `#Data` instructs excel we just want the data body not the title row or totals row.

To use a cell reference to choose the name of the column, you can use the `INDIRECT` function as discussed in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/461075/dynamically-reference-a-named-table-column-via-cell-content-in-excel). Specifically, use text concatenation to merge in to the formula text from the cell containing the column name, then indirect will convert that string to the table reference:

For example `INDIRECT("Table1[[#Data],["&D7&"]]")` where in this case `D7` contains the column name.

[image: Formulas with Indirect]

The result of the structured access is an array of cells, one for each cell in the table column. You can use `INDEX(array, row)` to select a specific cell from this array.

[image: Evaluated]

Note that the row number is not the global excel row number, but rather the row within the data region - so row 1 would be "Hello" in this example.

Comment: I would try to avoid using Indirect if not necessary because it is volatile, so it will trigger lots of recalculations that might not be needed. Use Match to find the column name in the headers and Index to return the whole column, as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to use MATCH to compare your text string against all the headers to find the column number. Put that inside an INDEX to return the whole column. You can use that to do things like a SUM of the whole column, or use the column in other formulas.

If you are already doing a MATCH to find a particular row, you can just use both matches inside the same INDEX. Using your example of your string in cell $L$1, against a Table I have lazily left being called Table1, I can get a SUM of that column:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table1,,MATCH($L$1,Table1[#Headers],0)))
```

Notice the double comma - the first one would be to put in a row number, the second says that this MATCH is returning a **column** number.

Let's say you are trying to get a particular row value from that column, for Customer = Acme that might look something like this:

```
=INDEX(Table1,MATCH("Acme Plc",Table1[Customer],0),MATCH($L$1,Table1[#Headers],0))
```